# Seeking London building shapefile

Tags: shapefile, united-kingdom, building, residential

I need a London building shapefile. I attempted to use Microsoft footprint, but encountered difficulties. I also tried downloading from Overpass without success.

How can I find a reliable way to obtain this information?

Specifically, I am looking for shapefile data for residential buildings. If there are additional details on building types, that would be excellent. However, if not, I can supplement the information.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Data requests aren't a good fit for our Focused question/Best answer model. If you want to [Edit] this to focus on the "difficulties" encountered, then we have a better chance of answering.

Comment: "I also tried downloading from Overpass without success." Details would help.

Comment: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/united-kingdom/england/greater-london.html (shp.zip has buildings)